# Error: Failed to apply catalog: Could not find dependency Class[Zeo] for Class[Z eo::Install] in PUPPET

Tags: puppet

I was trying to install zeo service from puppet master in windows agent and I got the following error:

`Error: Failed to apply catalog: Could not find dependency Class[Zeo] for Class[Z eo::Install] in PUPPET`

I have module called `zeo` and its manifests init.pp and make.pp and install.pp

But Its failing to reach init.pp and class zeo

```
# make.pp
class zeo::make {

  notify{" make.pp client mass section zope/init.pp": }
  require zeo
  #....
  #....
  #....
}


# install.pp
class zeo::install {

  notify{"client mass section zope/init.pp ${title}": }

  require zeo::make
  #....
  #....
  #....

}

# init.pp
class zeo {

  require prerequisite::install
  #....
  #....
  #....
}
```

Please help me to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

Please debug as:

1) Checkout your module path i.e : **puppet config print modulepath**
2) Module name i.e zeo should be same as your class name as it is case sensitive.**In refrence to your class name i.e "zeo" and module name is "Zeo" (as appeared in error message)** .
3) Comment out this line "require prerequisite::install" as we don't know whether prerequisite::install class exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

You did not show where you are calling zeo::install.

So 2 options :

- make sure you do not mean `require zeo::install` instead of `require prerequisite::install`
- Make sure the directories are :

> ```
>  modules
>     |_ zeo
>         |- manifests
>              |- init.pp
>              |- make.pp
>              |- install.pp
>     |_ prerequiste
>         |- manifests
>              |- init.pp
>              |- install.pp
> ```